# Remove NAs before group_by and summarise in user-defined function

Tags: r

Mock data:

```
df = structure(list(country = c("USA", "USA", "Japan", NA), dimension = c("economic", 
"cultural", "economic", "economic"), score = c(NA, "high", "high", 
"low")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I wrote this function to summarise frequencies of each variable, then export them to a csv with the name of the variable as the file name:

```
export <- function(df){   
  for (col in colnames(df)) {  
    table <- df %>%
      group_by(df[col]) %>%
      summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
      mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count)*100,
             N = sum(Count))
    write.csv(table, paste0(col, ".csv"), row.names = F)
    print(table)
  }                            
}             

export(df) --> this works
```

But I would like to remove the NA before grouping the data and computing frequencies. I did so:

```
export <- function(df){   
  for (col in colnames(df)) {  
    table <- df %>%
      filter(!is.na(df[col])) %>%  # Attempt to filter out NAs
      group_by(df[col]) %>%
      summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
      mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count)*100,
             N = sum(Count))
    write.csv(table, paste0(col, ".csv"), row.names = F)
    print(table)
  }                            
}  

export(df) --> this does not work, and I get this error message:

Error in `group_by()`:
ℹ In argument: `df[col]`.
Caused by error:
! `df[col]` must be size 3 or 1, not 4.
```

How do I remove these NAs?? I must have made a silly mistake here.

CURRENT OUTPUT (only the first of the three variables to iterate over is shown):

```
country Count   Percent N
Japan   1       25      4
USA     2       50      4
NA      1       25      4
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (only the first of the three variables to iterate over is shown):

```
country Count   Percent     N
Japan   1       33.33333    3
USA     2       66.66667    3
```

Note that NA are discarded and not included in frequencies.

Comment: In general, instead of `filter()` you could try `na.omit()`.

Comment: You shouldn't reference `df` within a dplyr verb. You can use the `.data` keyword to do non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Same error with na.omit(). I wish to group over each variable in the data set--not one variable in particular

Comment: @Gregor Thomas thanks, but do you have a solution?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. If you want the count of non-NA values in each column, I would use `df |> summarize(across(everything(), \(x) sum(!is.na(x))), .by = .data[[col]])`. If you want to drop all rows that have a `NA` value anywhere, then `df |> na.omit() |> ...`

Comment: @GregorThomas I added my desired output. I don't want to remove all rows that have NA, but to remove NA for each variable separately/iteratively. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few options, all giving the same result:

```
export2 <- function(df){   
  for (col in colnames(df)) {  
    table <- df %>%
      filter(if_any(all_of(col), \(x) !is.na(x))) |>
      summarise(Count = n(), .by = all_of(col)) %>% 
      mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count)*100,
             N = sum(Count))
    #write.csv(table, paste0(col, ".csv"), row.names = F)
    print(table)
  }                            
}             

export2(df)
#   country Count  Percent N
# 1     USA     2 66.66667 3
# 2   Japan     1 33.33333 3
#   dimension Count Percent N
# 1  economic     3      75 4
# 2  cultural     1      25 4
#   score Count  Percent N
# 1  high     2 66.66667 3
# 2   low     1 33.33333 3


export3 <- function(df){   
  for (col in colnames(df)) {  
    table <- df %>%
      select(all_of(col)) |>
      na.omit() |>
      summarise(Count = n(), .by = all_of(col)) %>% 
      mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count)*100,
             N = sum(Count))
    #write.csv(table, paste0(col, ".csv"), row.names = F)
    print(table)
  }                            
}            

export3(df)
# same as above 

export4 <- function(df){   
  for (col in colnames(df)) {  
    table <- df %>%
      select(all_of(col)) |>
      na.omit() |> 
      count(.data[[col]], name = "Count") |>
      mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count)*100,
             N = sum(Count))
    #write.csv(table, paste0(col, ".csv"), row.names = F)
    print(table)
  }                            
}    

export4(df)
# same as above
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using `group_by_at()` which has been superseeded, but it is only a slight change from your attempt. You can use `col` directly since it accepts a character vector.

Edit:
Alternatively, you can use `group_by(pick({{ col }})` in place of `group_by_at(col)`.

```
export1 <- function(df){   
    for (col in colnames(df)) {  
        table <- df %>%
            filter(!is.na(df[col])) %>%  # Attempt to filter out NAs
            group_by_at(col) %>% # <-- HERE
            summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
            mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count)*100,
                   N = sum(Count))
        #write.csv(table, paste0(col, ".csv"), row.names = F)
        print(table)
    }                            
}  

export1(df)

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  country Count Percent     N
  <chr>   <int>   <dbl> <int>
1 Japan       1    33.3     3
2 USA         2    66.7     3
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  dimension Count Percent     N
  <chr>     <int>   <dbl> <int>
1 cultural      1      25     4
2 economic      3      75     4
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  score Count Percent     N
  <chr> <int>   <dbl> <int>
1 high      2    66.7     3
2 low       1    33.3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to stay in `base R`, we can make use of the convenient way `table()` deals with `NA`'s:

**Function**

```r
foo = \(input, by) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(input))
  x = table(input[by])
  xn = as.numeric(x); sxn = sum(x)
  xx = setNames(data.frame(rownames(x), xn, 100L * xn/sxn, sxn),
                c(by, "count", "percent", "N"))
  write.csv(xx, paste0(by, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  xx # maybe: print(xx)
}
```

**Apply**

```r
lapply(colnames(df), \(j) foo(df, j))
#> [[1]]
#>   country count  percent N
#> 1   Japan     1 33.33333 3
#> 2     USA     2 66.66667 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   dimension count percent N
#> 1  cultural     1      25 4
#> 2  economic     3      75 4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   score count  percent N
#> 1  high     2 66.66667 3
#> 2   low     1 33.33333 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(country = c("USA", "USA", "Japan", NA), dimension = c("economic", 
                                                                           "cultural", "economic", "economic"), score = c(NA, "high", "high", 
                                                                                                                          "low")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```